# Read file using GetManisfestResourceStream or URI pack

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read a file which is located under properties/test.properties in a different reference.  I tried to read the file using

1. Using pack : pack://application:,,,/TestRef;component/properties/test.properties.
2. this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestRef.properties.test.properties");

Having issue with reading in both scenarios.

Comment: Show some code. How can anyone help you fix your code - without seeing your code?

Comment: 1)  Uri uri = new Uri ("pack://application:,,,/TestRef;component/properties/test.properties");
 Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;

2) Stream s = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestRef.properties.test.properties");

I tried above 2 ways.  In both scenarios, I get error "Unable locate resource properties/test.properties

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: BTW, what makes you think that test.properties is a resource?